# Fill between: How to cover a line that goes cross a filled region?

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I am trying to draw a figure where a red line runs cross a region filled with blue. No matter how I tweak the fill opacity. It seems that the red line is always ``one layer" above the shaded region. Is there anything I can do to make the shaded region one layer above the line? Thanks.

Edit:

I draw the red lines first (code at the bottom), and then fill blue region. And the graph on the right hand side is with solid fill (fill opacity=1), but the red lines still stand out. So I am after a solution for the red line to be under the blue filled region.
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
          % height=207pt, % default height
          height=200pt,          
          % height=160pt,
          % width=\axisdefaultwidth,
          font=\footnotesize,
          axis lines=middle,
          xtick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
          ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
          xmin=0, xmax=1,
          ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
          clip=false,
          axis equal
    ]
    % shaded regions for a
    \addplot[red, very thick, name path = a] coordinates{(0,0.2) (0,0.8) (1,0.8)};
    \addplot[red, very thick, name path = b] coordinates{(0,0.2) (1,0.2) (1,0.8)};
    \addplot[fill = red, fill opacity=0.5] fill between[of = a and b, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
    % shaded regions for b
    \addplot[blue, very thick, name path = c] coordinates{(0.2,0) (0.2,1) (0.8,1)};
    \addplot[blue, very thick, name path = d] coordinates{(0.2,0) (0.8,0) (0.8,1)}; 
    \addplot[fill = blue, fill opacity=0.5] fill between[of = c and d, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
          % height=207pt, % default height
          height=200pt,          
          % height=160pt,
          % width=\axisdefaultwidth,
          font=\footnotesize,
          axis lines=middle,
          xtick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
          ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
          xmin=0, xmax=1,
          ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
          clip=false,
          axis equal
    ]
    % shaded regions for a
    \addplot[red, very thick, name path = a] coordinates{(0,0.2) (0,0.8) (1,0.8)};
    \addplot[red, very thick, name path = b] coordinates{(0,0.2) (1,0.2) (1,0.8)};
    \addplot[fill = red, fill opacity=0.5] fill between[of = a and b, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
    % shaded regions for b
    \addplot[blue, very thick, name path = c] coordinates{(0.2,0) (0.2,1) (0.8,1)};
    \addplot[blue, very thick, name path = d] coordinates{(0.2,0) (0.8,0) (0.8,1)}; 
    \addplot[fill = blue, fill opacity=1] fill between[of = c and d, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. Can you show us the example code you have (only the figure)? It will be easier (and more motivating) for people to answer.

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Check for `opacity`, `fill opacity` and `text opacity` in the [manual](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: first draw the red line then fill the region

Comment: Thanks for the comment, an example with code is added. @mickep

Comment: Thanks for the comment, an example with code is added. @FHZ

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought might solve the problem but it didn't. See my edited post. @HafidBoukhoulda

Comment: Please Have a look at what a MWE is. Remove all unneeded code and make it compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion!

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
          % height=207pt, % default height
          height=200pt,          
          % height=160pt,
          % width=\axisdefaultwidth,
          font=\footnotesize,
          axis lines=middle,
          xtick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
          ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
          xmin=0, xmax=1,
          ymin=0, ymax=1.2,
          clip=false,
          axis equal
    ]
    % shaded regions for a
    \filldraw[red,very thick](0,0.2)--(0,0.8)--(1,0.8)--(1,0.2)--cycle;
   
    % shaded regions for b
    \filldraw[blue, very thick] 
    (0.2,0)--(0.2,1)--(0.8,1)--(0.8,0)--cycle;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]